# inserting to database using ado command

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado

I am trying to insert records into a table using adodb using c++.

Stored Proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbo.insert_command]
  @Id INT OUTPUT,
  @Name    varchar(25),
  @Age   int = NULL
  -- WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
...
```

Declaring the commands:

```
TESTHR(m_pInsertCommand.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command)));
    m_pInsertCommand>ActiveConnection = m_pConnection;
    m_pInsertCommand>CommandText = L"dbo.insert_command";
    m_pInsertCommand>Parameters->Append(m_pInsertCommand->CreateParameter(L"Id", adInteger, adParamOutput, 4, vtNull));
    m_pInsertCommand>Parameters->Append(m_pInsertCommand->CreateParameter(L"Name", adVarChar, adParamInput, m_lLabelLength));
    m_pInsertCommand>Parameters->Append(m_pInsertCommand->CreateParameter(L"Age", adInteger, adParamInput, sizeof(long), vtNull));
```

Setting the parameters:

```
dbConnection.m_pInsertCommand->Parameters->Item[L"Id"]->Value = vtNull;
dbConnection.m_pInsertCommand->Parameters->Item[L"Name"]->Value = (BSTR) m_Name;
dbConnection.ExecuteCommand(dbConnection.m_pInsertCommand, adCmdStoredProc | adExecuteNoRecords);
Id = (long) dbConnection.m_pInsertDefectCommand->Parameters->Item[L"Id"]->Value;
```

Trace through SQL Profiler:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=16
exec dbo.insert_Command @p1 output,'Name',NULL
select @p1
```

My question is why is the command generating the parameter @p1 in the sql statement. this is causing the logic to change as I am trying to insert a record if the parameter id is null.

Any suggestions for why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have difined @Id as ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamOutput and your input value is ignored. if you need read/test input value and set output value try using ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInputOutput.

Comment: the problem is that whenever there is an output parameter the ado command is declaring the output parameter as a variable in the T-SQL block without any explicit reasons (here @p1). Any reasons for that?